# How to call a function containing state change from target.value to useEffect() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have an error *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')* for this code:

```js
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

const handleChangeTitle = (e) => {
  setTitle(e.target.value);
};

useEffect(() => {
  handleChangeTitle()
}, [title]);

return (
  <div className="App">
    <input
      name="title"
      type="text"
      value={title}
      onChange={handleChangeTitle}
    />
    <p>{title}</p>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Because you're not passing anything to the function, so `e` is `undefined`.  More to the point... What are you trying to accomplish with this?  Every time `title` changes you want to change `title`?  Why?  What is that meant to accomplish besides potentially crashing the app with an endless re-render loop?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the useEffect altogether. useEffect is for lifecycle events such as on initial render. What you're doing is when the input changes you update your state. That's fine call handleChangeTitle exactly as you are doing. However, your useEffect has a dependency on the title variable. That means anytime it changes it will fire every time that variable's value changes.

```
input -> value change -> handleChangeTitle updates state "title" -> useEffect fires -> calls handleChangeTitle AGAIN -> cycle over and over until app crashes
```

Besides the already called out missing parameter to handleChangeTitle there is nothing wrong with your code. It's working as intended. It's just flawed in its design. I would suggest reading up on the correct usage of each hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Answer (score -1):

you are already watching [title] inside you useEffect , whenever onChange event fired the function will called , as Szymon Said you don't your onChange inside your useEffect

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).